# Dask converts list of tuples to list of list from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe

I recently came across an issue that Dask converts list of tuples to list of listfrom pandas while applying a function on a groupby after converting a Pandas dataframe to Dask dataframe. Below is a small reproducible example:

```
abc = [[("a", 1), ("b", 2)], [("a", 1), ("b", 2)], [("a", 1), ("b", 2)], [("a", 1), ("b", 2)]]
mnp = [1, 1, 2, 3]
pdf1 = pd.DataFrame()
pdf1["a"] = abc
pdf1["b"] = mnp
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf1, npartitions=2)
def apply_fun(grouped_df):
    print(grouped_df)

pdf1.groupby(["b"]).apply(apply_fun) # pandas version
ddf.groupby(["b"]).apply(apply_fun, meta=pd.Series([], dtype=str)).compute() # dask version
```

The pandas version produces

```
                  a  b
0  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  1
1  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  1
                  a  b
2  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  2
                  a  b
3  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  3
```

the dask version

```
                  a  b
0  [[a, 1], [b, 2]]  1
1  [[a, 1], [b, 2]]  1
                  a  b
2  [[a, 1], [b, 2]]  2
                  a  b
3  [[a, 1], [b, 2]]  3
```

Could someone please help how to retain the original format as a list of tuples?

Comment: Please show what you expect/want the result to be, and what you got instead or any exception (with full traceback).

Comment: The expectation for the output of print statement is for column "a" to be a list of tuple instead of a list of list. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question including all the details I asked for. Be specific.

Comment: Sure, I've modified the question with specific details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The tuple/list switch happens during aggregation (probably an `iter` somewhere), but if the specific datatype should be retained, it's possible to explicitly impose it:

```py
def apply_fun(grouped_df):
    grouped_df["a"] = grouped_df["a"].apply(lambda x: [tuple(y) for y in x])
    print(grouped_df)
#                   a  b
# 0  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  1
# 1  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  1
#                   a  b
# 2  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  2
#                   a  b
# 3  [(a, 1), (b, 2)]  3
```

Comment: Explicit transformation could definitely help. But, I am looking for a better solution without explicit transformation. Thanks.